# How to use callback functions of Gurobi in Drake

Tags: callback, gurobi, drake

I am solving hybrid control problems using Drake with Gurobi solver. I want to get the final root relaxed solution (after presolve and auto cut generation). I tried writing log files, but the log file doesn't print out every iteration and I couldn't get the best relaxed objective bound after presolve and cut generation.

[Get root node relaxation solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55774848/19456305)
This post shows how to retrieve the value I want, but I am not sure how to change the code to use it in Drake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In GurobiSolver, we provide adding callback functions for mixed-integer program, you can check [AddMipNodeCallback](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_gurobi_solver.html#a94d6956a6a9ef1ac012dcf6c582ef3cc) or [AddMipSolCallback](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_gurobi_solver.html#abf6160a85e2371861c1736ab163a9b8f)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still am stuck with this. I am using Python. Does the callback functions also work for Pydrake? Also, can you give an example code? ( Maybe for this line : nodecount = model.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIPNODE_NODCNT)

Comment: @JisunLee Thanks for using Drake! Let me ruminate on the design of Drake's callback function, possibly I will make some change before adding it to pydrake. I will let you know when we finalize the design.

Comment: Wondering if there is any progress on this issue. I also have one more question. Can we model constraints with bilinear terms in Pydrake? I see that there is a function 'ReplaceBilinearTerms' in Drake but not in Pydrake.

Comment: @JisunLee I think we will use the current callback. I will add them to pydrake. Sorry for the delay

Comment: Thank you. Could you also add the function 'ReplaceBilinearTerms' to Pydrake? Or are there other methods that I can use bilinear terms in the constraints in Pydrake?

Comment: @JisunLee Sorry it took a while, I have added the python binding for both the call back and ReplaceBilinearTerms into pydrake.